# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{a} x^3 (ax-x^2)^{\frac 32} dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The integral can be written as
\begin{align}
\int_0^a (a-x)^3 (ax-x^2)^{\frac 32} dx &=\int_0^a (a-x)^3 x^{\frac 32} (a-x)^{\frac 32} dx\\
&=\int_0^a (a-x)^{\frac 92} x^{\frac 32} dx
\end{align}

How do I solve further?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Put $x=az, dx=a\ dz$  to reach at [Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) function

Alternatively,  set $x=a\sin^2t$   to reach at [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html)   $$B(m+1,n+1)=\dfrac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!}$$

Comment: Well, is involvement of beta function necessary?